# Unchecked read from a map in a const function

Tags: c++

Suppose the following:

```
struct C {
    ... // lots of other stuff
    int get(int key) const { return m.at(key); } // This will never throw
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
};
```

Due to how the application works, I know that `get` never throws. I want to make `get` as fast as possible. So, I would like to make the access unchecked, i.e. I would like to write something like `return m[key]`. Of course, I cannot write exactly that while keeping `get` const. However, I want to keep `get` const, since it *is* logically const.

Here is the only (ugly) solution I came up with:

```
struct C {
    ... // lots of other stuff
    int get(int key) const { return const_cast<C *>(this)->m[key]; }
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
};
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you think that `m.at(key)` is significantly less efficient that `m[key]`? Have you timed them? The main work, to find the key, is the same, the only difference is in what happens if the key is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I object to the very reasoning behind this question. The overhead (of `map.at()` vs `map[]`) associated with catching an error due to unknown `key` is presumably tiny compared to the cost of finding the `key` in the first place.
Yet, you willingly take the serious risk of a run-time error just for such a marginal efficiency advantage that you presumably have not even validated/measured. You may think that you know that `key` is always contained in the map, but perhaps future code changes (including bugs introduced by others) may change that?

If you really know, then you should use

```
map.find(key)->second;
```

which makes the bug explicit if the iterator returned is invalid (i.e. equal to `map.end()`). You may use `assert` in pre-production code, i.e.

```
auto it = map.find(key);
assert(it!=map.end());
return it->second;
```

which in production code (when `assert` is an empty macro) is removed.

Comment: I saw the advice to use `[]` when efficiency is needed in **The C++ Programming Language** (4th edition) by Bjarne Stroustrup. However, I cannot find this statement now and am not sure now that he was talking about maps rather than vector. I agree with your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use `std::unordered_map::find`:

```
struct C {
    ... // lots of other stuff
    int get(int key) const { return m.find(key)->second; }
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
};
```

Comment: This is the correct way, **iff** it is guaranteed that the `key` is contained in the map.

Comment: Indeed. The OP asked for unchecked access, but if you're not certain that the key is present, then the iterator should be compared with `m.end()` before dereferencing it.